# Connect to connected OpenVPN client from different subnet

Tags: networking, openvpn, remote-access, subnet

I have a machine running Xubuntu 17.04 that is connected as a client to a VPN via OpenVPN (2.3.11). When I have the client connected, I can access the machine remotely via SSH and VNC if I am on the same subnet (my LAN subnet, 192.168.1.0/24). I can not access it from my wireless subnet, 192.168.2.1/24. If I disconnect from OpenVPN I can connect from the wireless subnet. I do not have access to the server to make config changes as this is a paid VPN service. Is there a way to allow the incoming connection from multiple subnets while OpenVPN is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific steps to answer this question for my case:

Stop OpenVPN if running

```
sudo service openvpn stop
```

Create a script file. I'll use `up-route.sh`

```
sudo nano /etc/openvpn/up-route.sh
```

Add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

Edit your OpenVPN config file. In my case it is `/etc/openvpn/vpn.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/openvon/vpn.conf
```

Add the following lines to the bottom:

```
script-security 2
up up-route.sh
```

Save and Exit. Start OpenVPN again:

```
sudo service openvpn start
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of missing information in you questions:

1) When you say "I can not access it from my wireless subnet", it sounds like you have access problems to connect to this OpenVPN client, on your local LAN, from your local WiFi network: In this case you might be having access troubles on the WiFi router.

2) If you want the WiFi network to connect through the OpenVPN connection, then you would need to 
a) add the WiFi network to the network that is routed down the OpenVPN link, and also confirm the OpenVPN client have the needed route(s) to the WiFi Network, and that the WiFi router have the needed rules, routes and access settings to point the right network via the OpenVPN client.

Pictures on the setup and what needs to achieve would really help to answer your question correctly

Comment: I don't know how I could have made it more clear. I am not trying to connect through the host in question. Only trying to connect to it directly while it is connected to the VPN. Is isn't a router issue. It connects fine when it isn't connected. The issue only arises when the host in question is connected to the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN and others, have a setting like "Sent all traffic through VPN" or "Default Gateway VPN"

This goal of this setting, is to (1) override the "actual" default gateway where you want to bypass local firewall filtering, and (2) for corporate type access where you have more than jsut the VPN "local" net behind the VPN.

This is the setting that you most probably want to have active, but this now interferes with your WiFi connectivity.

The way *Around* this:
Add a separate route to the wifi router on your host:

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via

IF the above fails, or you don't know the IPs:
give an output (while the VPN is connected) of:

`ip route show`

and  also when the VPN is *NOT* conencted:

`traceroute -n <ip-of-device-on-wif>`